# How To Get Leading Space To Be 1/3 The Width Of the SuperView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I am trying to set an icon to be 1/3 along the width of the superview.

However when I set the width it's only give me hard values as the option.

Is it possible to set the x position of an object to be 1/3rd the width through the interface builder?

[image]

Thanks

Update:

Trying to set a .leading against a .width does not appear to be an option for leading:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make the constraint between the icon's centerX and the superview's trailing. In the images below, first, and third refer to the first and third icons. The constraints will put the first one 1/3 of the way from the left edge, and the third one 1/3 of the way in from the right edge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, just brilliant thank you! This is going to help me with a lot of viewclasses. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the widths to be equal with a multiplier of 1/3

[image]

Sorry misread question. You could do something like

```
// self.imageView is a reference to the image view (or view, whatever it is)
// and self.leadingConstraint is a constraint on the imageView's leading/X constraint
// probably have to recalculate on rotation (maybe, didn't test)
CGFloat constant = self.imageView.superview.frame.size.width / 3;
self.leadingConstraint.constant = constant;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

In IB

Not perfect but ¯_(ツ)_/¯

[image: higher the number, further left it goes]

Comment: Yes but I am trying to get the Leading Space to be 1/3 The super view width.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can figure out how to do that, based on mittens' example.

Comment: If you take a look at the new screen shot, you'll see I cannot set a .Leading against a .Width

Comment: Ya doing it in code is no issue, do you know how to do it via the interface builder?:)